# How to compute the rational group of this elliptic curve?

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves

How to compute the rational group of this elliptic curve:

$$E:\quad y^2=(x+3)x(x-1).$$

Ps:  I am not familar with elliptic curves. (1,0), (0,0), (-3,0), (-1, 2), (-1, -2), (3, 6), (3, -6) are obviously rational points of E(Q), I guess that E(Q) is isomorphic to Z4×Z2, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: There is a method called $2$-descent for elliptic curves whose cubic part has three distinct roots. See Silverman's book or Wikipedia.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not familar with the elliptic curves. In fact, (1,0), (0,0), (-3,0), (-1, 2), (-1, -2), (3, 6), (3, -6) are obviously rational points of E(Q), I guess that E(Q) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4 \times \mathbb{Z}_2$, but I cannot prove it.

Comment: @JunhuaHe In general, it is better if you can provide information on what you have tried when you post a question. Even just the comment you made about would be better than nothing. (I just thought you'd like to know, for future reference :-) )

Comment: Thank you for your remind and comment. I am sorry that it is the first time I come here for answer of a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are right. The rank is $0$, and the torsion subgroup is isomorphic to $E_{tor}=\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, with generators $(3,6)$, $(0,1)$. 
Hence $E(\mathbb{Q})\simeq E_{tor}$.
Substituting $x$ by $x-1$ we obtain the minimal Weierstrass equation
$$
E\colon y^2=x^3-x^2-4x+4.
$$
All integer points are given by your above list. 
There are several results you can use to prove this, such as Nagell-Lutz for the torsion
subgroup, and for the rank the fact that the L-series value 
$$L(E,1)=0.539128911875$$ is nonzero (the order of vanishing is the analytic rank of $E$, which in this case is known to be the rank of $E$).
One can also check this by a computation in the online database (with $E=[0,2,0,-3,0]$) 
http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q.

Comment: Thank you very much! I can use some theorems in the book by Silverman and Tate proved that $E_{tor}=\mathbb{Z}_4\times \mathbb{Z}_2$, but I don't know how to compute the rank of $E(\mathbb{Q})$. Thank you again for your sugestion to compute the L-series value by online database.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to compute the rank yourself, for curves like this with full 2-torsion it is often not too hard by hand: see Silverman's book "The Arithmetic of elliptic curves".  Or you can use the implementations available in (for example) Sage:

```
sage: E = EllipticCurve([0,2,0,-3,0])
sage: E.label()
'24a1'
sage: E.rank() 
0
sage: E.torsion_points()
[(-3 : 0 : 1),
 (-1 : -2 : 1),
 (-1 : 2 : 1),
 (0 : 0 : 1),
 (0 : 1 : 0),
 (1 : 0 : 1),
 (3 : -6 : 1),
 (3 : 6 : 1)]
```

Here the label shows that this curve is in the database, so that in fact Sage need not compute the rank but could just look it up:

```
sage: E.rank(use_database=True)
0
```

By default, Sage does do the computation (it includes my eclib library which includes the program mwrank to compute ranks).